How to use only these definitions and assumptions to prove that $\nexists A$ such that $A\neq A$?
Edit:
It seems to me that if "$\nexists A$ such that $A\neq A$" is true then we should be able to show that:
Taking $P_2$ to be true leads to an inconsistency, because it allows for the construction of a P-proposition whose truth value cannot be decided between 'true' and 'false', thereby violating (4).
However, my current best guess is that the statement I wish to prove is actually not provable within this particular axiomatic system, because we lack a way of showing that "$A\neq A$" is the negation of "$A=A$" within this system.

Establish:

Define "$A=B$" to mean that $A$ and $B$ have exactly the same set of properties $\tag1$
Define "$A\neq B$" to mean that $A$ and $B$ do not have exactly the same set of properties $\tag2$
Define a 'P-proposition' as any statement which is either true, false or both (not neither) $\tag3$
Assume without proof that no P-proposition is both true and false $\tag4$
Assume without proof that if $A$ has one or more properties then $A=A$ $\tag5$
Assume without proof that statements $P_1, P_2, P_3, P_4$ and $P_5$ are P-propositions $\tag6$

Let $A$ be such that it has one or more properties

$P_1$: $\forall A$, $A=A$
$P_2$: $\exists A$ such that $A\neq A$ and $A=A$ simultaneously
$P_3$: $\exists A$ such that $A\neq A$
$P_4$: $P_2$ is true
$P_5$: $P_2$ is false

The only reason I thought I'd include $P_4$ and $P_5$ is on the off chance that maybe some clever highly-layered reasoning about the truth or falsity of P-propositions about the truth or falsity of other P-propositions might be able to get the job done
How do I prove that $P_3$ is false without introducing additional definitions or assumptions?

The farthest I could get was pointing out these two things:
By (5), $P_1$ is true.
Therefore, $P_3$ can be true only if $P_2$ is true, and it is false if $P_2$ is false.
So now it suffices to only prove that $P_2$ is false, which I have no idea how to do within this particular system either.

I think your $P_1$ is missing a quantifier. To me that looks like a sentence where either you're taking about a particular (previously established) $A$, or it's a sentence that takes a set as input and evaluates whether that input makes the sentence true or not. In either case it doesn't have a truth value by itself, and therefore doesn't look like a P-sentence to me. Maybe you should write "$\forall A, A = A$"?

What are “definite properties”? They don’t seem to be defined (perhaps this is a standard term I’m unfamiliar with)

@msantama I've made a change. You're right that the term was nonstandard, and instead of choosing to define it I've found it best to modify the question so as to avoid using the term

@MauroALLEGRANZA Is the fact that "$\forall A(P(A) \leftrightarrow P(A))$" and "$\nexists A$ such that $A\neq A$" are equivalent statements entailed by the 6 established parts of this particular axiomatic system? Or are you bringing something in from outside the axiomatic system laid out in this question? Obviously this is normally the case, but my intuition is that the axiomatic system I've laid out in the question might not follow conventional rules, because it's missing crucial parts of what constitute most classical logics.

particularly, I'm interested in knowing which of the 6 part(s) of the axiomatic system is/are violated by taking $P_2$ to be true

In order to have a notion of proof, we need more than axioms and definitions, we need to know what rules of inference we can use.

You haven't defined what a property is. What does it mean for A to have a set of properties? And what does it mean for two sets of properties to be the same? You define A = B, via Set of Properties of A = Set of Properties of B. But we don't know what the latter half of that definition is supposed go mean.

If you define $A = B ↔ ∀P(P(A) ↔ P(B))$ (see Identity) we have that $A≠B$ is $¬(A=B) ↔ ∃P(P(A) ∧ ¬P(B))$.
By the tautology $P(A) ↔ P(A)$ we conclude $∀A(P(A) ↔ P(A))$ that is $¬∃A¬(P(A) ↔ P(A))$ i.e. $¬∃A¬(A=A)$.
If we want to "found" logic from scratch, we have to state some axioms for logical connectives and quantifiers. If not, we have to assume the usual laws for negation and quantifiers and thus, from $∀A(A=A)$ and the fact that $∀$ is $¬∃¬$  we immediately derive $¬∃A¬(A=A)$.
Thus, if you want to achieve your project, you have to state at least the basic inference rules: Modus Ponens and Generalization, and some axioms and rules managing the negation sign.

I would venture to say you cannot. By $(3)$ and $(4)$ we know $P_2$ must either be true or false, so $P_4$ and $P_5$ are redundant.
You then have three statements each of which can true or false for a total of 8 cases to consider. If $P_1$, $P_2$, and $P_3$ are all true then the statement you wish to prove is false. There is no contradiction in assuming $P_1$, $P_2$, and $P_3$ are all true.

The only reason I thought I'd include $P_4$ and $P_5$ is on the off chance that maybe some clever highly-layered reasoning about the truth or falsity of P-propositions about the truth or falsity of other P-propositions might be able to get the job done.

Redundant as they may be, in the event that such a "layered" argument would work, rather than forcing MSE users to make their own versions of $P_4$ and $P_5$ I found it would make life easier to give such P-propositions and P-propositions names in advance.

Is this a textbook exercise or something? What gives you the impression that one should be able to prove the statement you desire?

I made it up. I was reflecting on axiomatic systems from classical logics, and wondered how exactly we normally come to the conclusion that $A=A$ if and only if it is false that $A\neq A$. Is it an unstated assumption of some sort that $A=A$ and $A\neq A$ are mutually exclusive? If so, does it go by a name in these logics?

I've also assumed that putting (3) and (4) together in the context of the rest of the system renders this system compatible with most classical logics.

I see. I’m not familiar with axiomatic systems and classical logic, but $A \neq A$ is the negation of $A =A$. You’re really asking how we know a statement $P$ is true if and only if $\neg P$ is false. Is that not an axiom?

I suppose the deeper question I'm attempting to get at is: by what means (either a deduction or just a quick reference to an axiom) would you typically justify the assertion that $A=A$ is necessarily the negation of $A\neq A$? I know that in non-classical logics it's not necessarily the case, so it makes me wonder exactly which feature (whether it be an axiom or not) of classical logics makes it the case that $A=A$ is necessarily the negation of $A\neq A$.
